# JDBI - How to map rowsets to java collections

Tags: java, dropwizard, jdbi

I am using JDBI 1.3.9 and dropwizard, I would like to know how to call into a stored procedure that returns a row set of values and map it to a java collection.

I have a stored procedure GET_EMP that returns rows of values as specified in the out parameters below.

**How do I map rowsets returned from a stored procedure into a collection of java objects**

**OUT PARAMETERS**
The out parameters returned are joining_date, department,employee_count, retired

where

- joining_date = date type
- department = varchar type
- employee_count = int type
- retired = bit type